# invalid conversion from int to avcodecid (ffmepg)

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

today when I run the ffmpeg example c program in CodeBlocks, I got the error:

```
invalid conversion from int to avcodecid[-fpermissive]
```

I put the part of the code here:

```
static AVCodec **codec;
static AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
static int  ret,   got_output;
static FILE *f;
static AVFrame *frame;
static AVPacket pkt;
static uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };
enum AVCodecID codec_id;

*codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);
```

No matter I use `*codec` or `codec`, it gives the same error, I have checked my opencv and ffmpeg version, all the newest version 2.4.10 opencv and 2.5.3 ffmpeg. 
And if I click the error, it direct me to another file `avcode.h`, gives error

> initializing agument 1 of 'AVcodec* acvodec_find_encoder(AVCodeciD)'[-fpermissive]

at this line of the file

```
frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
```

Comment: What's the return type of `avcodec_find_encoder`? Also you're using `codec_id` uninitialized there -- is that in your original code, or something you cut out?

Comment: The type of `avcodec_find_encoder`'s parameter is `AVCodecID`, not `int`. [Here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#gaadca229ad2c20e060a14fec08a5cc7ce) is the enum's documentation.

Comment: yes, I have changed the type from int to AVCodec and problem solved, sorry for my question, i did not put full program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message

> invalid conversion from int to avcodecid[-fpermissive]

means that there is no implicit conversion from `int` to type `enum AVCodecID`. So you need **explicitly cast** the integer to the type of the enumeration.

I suppose that you included all required headers did not you?

This error message

> initializing agument 1 of 'AVcodec*
>   acvodec_find_encoder(AVCodeciD)'[-fpermissive]

means that you are using a wrong argument type for the function call. You have to check the function declaration before calling it and supply correct arguments for its parameters.